# ubuntuでsambaをマウントできない

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba

Ubuntu機が２台ありファイルサーバ、解析サーバーを構築しています。
ファイルサーバにてsambaでファイル共有環境を構築、Macから接続が確認できました。
次に解析サーバーにてファイルサーバに接続、マウントしようとしましたがエラーが出ます。
vers=3.0, 2.0, 1.0や、mount.cifsなど試しましたが、どれもうまくいきません。

```bash
sudo mount -t cifs //IP-Address/media/share/hdd1 /mnt/fileserver1 -o username=test,password=test
```

エラー文
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount .cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)

Comment: cifs-utils がインストールされているか確認し、もしなければインストールしてみてください。 `sudo apt install cifs-utils`

Comment: `/mnt/fileserver1`というディレクトリは解析サーバー上に存在しますか？マウントポイントとなるディレクトリはマウント前に存在していなくてはなりません。